# Prevent percent Calculation over 100

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Below you will find my table DDL, inserts and query. I'm simply trying to calculate a percentage based on `my_budget` over `total_budget`. For all intents and purpose total budget is a static amount so it will not differentiate from row to row. The issue however is that in certain situations it appears that the total percent calculation is greater than 100%.
If you look at my results I end up with 100.01. Can someone give me a pointer how to prevent that from happening. I feel like I'm missing something simple on this one. I really don't care where the -.01 gets reduced from my percent calculation to get an even 100%.

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table PLAY_TABLE
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE PLAY_TABLE 
   (MY_BUDGET NUMBER(11,2), 
    VCOAS VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
    VFUND VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    VORGN VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    VACCT VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    TOTAL_BUDGET NUMBER(11,2)
   ) 
REM INSERTING into PLAY_TABLE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (535.5,'D','110001','3013','2041',101745);
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (4819.5,'D','110001','3304','2041',101745);
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (96390,'D','110001','3304','2211',101745);


SELECT round((my_budget / total_budget) * 100,  2) calculated_budget,
       total_budget,
       vcoas,
       vfund,
       vorgn,
       vacct,
       my_budget
  FROM play_table

 --results--
0.53    D   110001  3013    2041    535.5   101745
4.74    D   110001  3304    2041    4819.5  101745
94.74   D   110001  3304    2211    96390   101745
```

Comment: The results you’ve given don’t seem to show the 100.01 issue?

Comment: This is a simplified example . From a much larger query and problem that I'm trying to solve. I was trying to make the example easy to illustrate for people helping me.

Comment: Yes, but your examples don’t actually illustrate the problem - so it makes it difficult for anyone to help you. Please update your question to show sample data that does generate the issue you are facing

Comment: try summing @Nickw try summing (0.53+4.74+94.73) and than do the same with  (0.53+4.74+94.74)

Comment: The issue is with your ```ROUND``` to 2 decimals.  Add in more decimal places to the ```ROUND``` function until it SUMs to 100.

Comment: It is happening because of the rounding you use `ROUND(...,2)`; you can't avoid it! you can reduce its chances of happening by allowing more precision (don't round to 2 decimals) . Imagine having a budget of 100, and three entries of equal value, if you round to 2, they will have 33.3 each, and the total will be 99.9 but if you allow more precision, and only round the total you will see 100.00

Comment: @ tinazmu The actual table that my problem refers to , (not the play table I put above) needs the percents to be recorded this way.  Thats why im looking for a way to do it with the 2 decimal places . I realize that I will need to shave .01 from one of the percents to make be 100% I just cant fathom how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than rounding, you can truncate the values and you will get a total that is less than 100 and the amount you are out from 100 can be considered the "excess" that you need to distribute. After that, you can find the "difference" between the truncated value and the actual percentage and then spread that excess, in units of the smallest scale you are using (which for your example when you are rounding to 2 decimal places would be 0.01 or 1e-2) amongst the rows with the highest "difference".

Which would be:

```sql
SELECT calculated_budget +
         CASE
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY difference DESC) <= excess * 1e2
         THEN 1e-2
         ELSE 0
         END AS calculated_budget,
       total_budget,
       vcoas,
       vfund,
       vorgn,
       vacct,
       my_budget
FROM   (  
  SELECT TRUNC(my_budget / total_budget * 100 * 1e2) / 1e2 AS calculated_budget,
         my_budget / total_budget * 100 - TRUNC(my_budget / total_budget * 100 * 1e2) / 1e2
           AS difference,
         100 - SUM(TRUNC(my_budget / total_budget * 100 * 1e2) / 1e2) OVER () AS excess,
         total_budget,
         vcoas,
         vfund,
         vorgn,
         vacct,
         my_budget
  FROM   play_table
);
```

*Note: `100` represents converting decimal to a percentage and scientific notation (i.e. `1e2` and `1e-2`) is used when the numbers are dealing with the precision you are rounding to (i.e. 2 decimal places).*

Or, without the intermediate variables:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(my_budget / total_budget * 100 * 1e2) / 1e2 +
         CASE
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY my_budget / total_budget * 100
                           - TRUNC(my_budget / total_budget * 100 * 1e2) / 1e2 DESC
              ) <= (100 - SUM(TRUNC(my_budget / total_budget * 100 * 1e2) / 1e2) OVER ()) * 1e2
         THEN 1e-2
         ELSE 0
         END AS calculated_budget,
       total_budget,
       vcoas,
       vfund,
       vorgn,
       vacct,
       my_budget
FROM   play_table;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| CALCULATED_BUDGET | TOTAL_BUDGET | VCOAS | VFUND | VORGN | VACCT | MY_BUDGET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.74 | 101745 | D | 110001 | 3304 | 2041 | 4819.5 |
| 94.74 | 101745 | D | 110001 | 3304 | 2211 | 96390 |
| .52 | 101745 | D | 110001 | 3013 | 2041 | 535.5 |

---

If instead, you have the sample data:

```sql
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (1000,'D','110001','3013','2041',3000);
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (1000,'D','110001','3304','2041',3000);
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (1000,'D','110001','3304','2211',3000);
```

Where the values are all equal and would have 33.33% each (for a total of 99.99%), then the output will be:

| CALCULATED_BUDGET | TOTAL_BUDGET | VCOAS | VFUND | VORGN | VACCT | MY_BUDGET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33.34 | 3000 | D | 110001 | 3013 | 2041 | 1000 |
| 33.33 | 3000 | D | 110001 | 3304 | 2211 | 1000 |
| 33.33 | 3000 | D | 110001 | 3304 | 2041 | 1000 |

And an extra 0.01% has been added.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q9BqMaqO)

Comment: Absolutely awesome  Thank you ! I've never seen the use of `1e2` before. Thanks for that explanation. I appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After adding an identity to your table, as you need an order for the following code

You can calculate the running sum, and exclude or select the values that are bigger than the total_budget

but wouldn't it better to now allow inserts that give a over stepping of the budget in a trigger?

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table PLAY_TABLE
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE PLAY_TABLE 
   (ID NUMBER GENERATED by default on null as IDENTITY,
    MY_BUDGET NUMBER(11,2), 
    VCOAS VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
    VFUND VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    VORGN VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    VACCT VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    TOTAL_BUDGET NUMBER(11,2)
   )
```

```
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (535.5,'D','110001','3013','2041',101745);
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (4819.5,'D','110001','3304','2041',101745);
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
Insert into PLAY_TABLE (MY_BUDGET,VCOAS,VFUND,VORGN,VACCT,TOTAL_BUDGET) values (96390,'D','110001','3304','2211',101745);
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
WITH CTE as
  (SELECT round((my_budget / total_budget) * 100,  2) calculated_budget,
       total_budget,
       vcoas,
       vfund,
       vorgn,
       vacct,
       my_budget,
  SUM(my_budget) OVER( PARTITION BY VFUND ORDER BY ID) sum_
FROM PLAY_TABLE)
SELECT 
* FROM CTE WHERE total_budget > sum_
```

| CALCULATED_BUDGET | TOTAL_BUDGET | VCOAS | VFUND | VORGN | VACCT | MY_BUDGET | SUM_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .53 | 101745 | D | 110001 | 3013 | 2041 | 535.5 | 535.5 |
| 4.74 | 101745 | D | 110001 | 3304 | 2041 | 4819.5 | 5355 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rcd0VcOn)

Comment: The table is just an example of a much larger issue im dealing with. I was trying to simplify the problem by making simpler table containing the data that does not add 100%. Thanks for the answer but this is not quite it. I'm just trying to get a sum total of 100% based on the my budget/total_budget the way I'm doing it I end up with 100.01